# I Need Some Help On This Problem Concerning With The Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The Problem: Assume $\mu$ is known. Show this is an exponential family with parameter $\sigma$.

The Attempt: If I can show that the function $f(x| \sigma)$ can be written as $a(\sigma)t(x) +b(\sigma) +r(x) $. If I take the natural log of the function, this looks like

$ln(f(x|\sigma)) = ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp[\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}]) = -ln(\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma) - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$.

This is all I have so far. I tried completing the square for the second term but I did not get as far as I expected.

Is there something I am missing? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't you have this already? $b(\sigma)=-\log(\sqrt{2}\pi\sigma)$, $a=1/(2\sigma^2)$ etc.?

Comment: Okay. What about $t(x)$? In the second term, do I have to expand out $(x-\mu)^2$ ?

Comment: Do you understand why $a$ and $b$ are as they are?